# Any ideas how to troubleshoot HTTP Error 400 for MVC/Firefox?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, iis-7, http-error

Two clients complains on HTTP Error 400 from Mozilla Firefox 3.6.9. This happens when they open any link - both mvc application and also any static images, which are hosted on Classic application pool without any code.

Exact error message is **HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed**

No errors in windows log and application error log. Proxy in browser is set to off.

Other browsers works fine for them.

Any ideas about what could cause such behavior?

For now, i can see only one option - ask them to install Firebug, but this is not really user friendly.

Comment: Anything unusual with proxy settings? Firefox keeps its own ones.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Will it be displayed if I request for about:support ?

Comment: I asked user to check - No proxy :(

Comment: Why would you do client-side trouble-shooting? You have *all the information you need on the server-side*. Examine the request and determine why it is causing your server to respond with 400.

Comment: @bzlm: Do you have any instructions on how I can see request in this case?

Comment: @Sergey Turn on verbose server-side logging. I'm sure there's some way in your case to log the entire incoming requests. Seems you have found the problem, but I wouldn't be so fast to dismiss it as "corrupted cookies". :)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, cookies was corrupted and this was leading to HTTP 400 error.
After user cleaned cookies for this website he was able to get page.

I still need to investigate what exactly went wrong and find source of this problem but it is clear that I need to review all places where I do cookie creation.